# WPF Crystal Report problem using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I need to bind a List with a crystal report in my WPF application. Here is my code:

```
CrystalReportViewer crystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalReportViewer();
doctorCrystalReportObj.SetDataSource(appointmentManagerObj.GetDoctorList());
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doctorCrystalReportObj;
host.Child = crystalReportViewer1;
```

Report is generated. But no data found. Am I missing something? In windows forms application, there is an attribute **AutoDataBind="true"**. Is there anything similar in WPF Crystal Report?

Comment: I have solved the problem :D
Actually given code is fully ok. No need to autodatabind.
The problem occurred while mapping object to crystal report. So data was missing.